# NavigationExperimental Header set backgroundColor

Tags: react-native

Sorry for what has to be a basic noob question....

I can't figure out how to change the background color of the NavigationHeader component in NavigationExperimental.

Any tips?

Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to set the style prop on the `NavigationHeader` component.

You should be able to do something like:

```
<NavigationHeader
  {...props}
  style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}
  // Any of the other required props
/>
```

And then just make sure to render that NavigationHeader in the `renderOverlay` prop in the NavigationAnimatedView or any other component you decide to render the Header.